# Degree of smooth map of manifolds depends on orientation choice?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

I'm a little to confused as to why it appears that the degree of a smooth map $f: M \to N$ between smooth manifolds appears to only be defined up to sign - I'm not sure where my mistake is.

By definition $\textrm{deg}(f)$ is the unique integer such that:

$$\int_M f^*\alpha = \textrm{deg}(f) \int_N \alpha$$

Where $\alpha$ is any n-form on $N$. Now it seems that if I were to pick different orientation on $N$ then the integral on the right hand side would switch sign?

Comment: In order top define the degree, you need to have an orientation, and if you change the orientation of either the soirce or the target, this will change the sign of the degree. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping

Comment: Here $M$ and $N$ start off as compact, oriented manifolds.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I understand this now - the orientation is fixed when we choose an oriented manifold, if we have a different orientation this is a different oriented manifold right? I see this is a pretty stupid question, should I delete it?

Comment: For anyone wondering the same thing at a later point, this question is probably helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're onto something that is fully intended.

edit: here's a quote I think could be relevant

[image]

[source on google books](https://books.google.de/books?id=-B7yBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=mapping%20degree%20depends%20on%20orientation&source=bl&ots=xzo1Sx0RDV&sig=HVCjgjPdnC3CAqJwUxDQXLVTXzc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi638mg5erMAhVMOxQKHYlJBi0Q6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=mapping%20degree%20depends%20on%20orientation&f=false)